# Tweepy API doesn't download all tweets

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So I created a hashtag #tweet230720211255 and I want to download each and every tweet posted with this hashtag from last 7 days. So I used Tweepy and so far it does a good job of downloading tweets. But there is a problem that I'm facing.

Tweepy only downloads the tweets that has text in them. By that what I mean is if you post a tweet like [this](https://twitter.com/prk_00011/status/1418473349156507649?s=20) or [this](https://twitter.com/prk_00011/status/1418473181350793216?s=20), basically without any text except the hashtag, then it won't get downloaded. Would like some help here please. The code I have used is below:

```
#Scraping
import tweepy # for tweet mining
import csv # to read and write csv files
import glob


#Processing
import pandas as pd
import preprocessor as p
import requests
import string
import re # In-built regular expressions library
from collections import Counter


CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxx'
ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxx'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET) # Pass in Consumer key and secret for authentication by API
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET) # Pass in Access key and secret for authentication by API
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True) # Sleeps when API limit is reached

def get_tweets_in_data_range(data, phrase, max_tweets, end_date, start_date = None, start_via_tweet_id = None):
  search_query = phrase 
  #+ " -filter:links AND -filter:retweets AND -filter:replies" #Exclude links, retweets, replies
  for i in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = search_query, since = start_date, until = end_date, since_id = start_via_tweet_id, lang = "en", tweet_mode = "extended").items(max_tweets):
    data.append([i.full_text, i.id, i.created_at, i.coordinates, i.retweet_count, i.favorite_count]) # Embedded Twitter parameters


scraped_data = []
scraped_data.append(["text", "id", "time", "location", "retweet_count", "fav_count"])
PHRASE = "\"#tweet230720211255\""
MAX_TWEETS = 1000 #Maximum number of tweets to scrape
START_DATE = '2021-07-23' #only last 7 days supported
END_DATE = '2021-07-27' #only last 7 days supported
get_tweets_in_data_range(scraped_data, PHRASE, MAX_TWEETS, END_DATE, START_DATE) #call to get tweets between date ranges

cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id='burgerking', tweet_mode = "extended").items(1)
for i in cursor:
  print(dir(i))

tweets = pd.DataFrame(scraped_data[1:],columns=scraped_data[0])
tweets_csv = tweets.to_csv('download.csv', index=True)  #saves a csv file with the data scraped
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None,
                       'display.max_columns', None,
                       'display.precision', 3,
                       ):
  print(tweets)
```

Please point out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: First of all you’re trying to search, and the v1.1 search API is very limited, both to 7 days, and some very new accounts may be missed due to various factors. Plus, you are dependent on how Tweepy Python library talks to the API. Your “phrase” is a potentially brand new term. Twitter v1.1 search is limited.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the info...For those who still want to all the tweets can use `snscrape`, it pretty much does the job..