# Licensed API for twitter

Tags: twitter, tweepy

Right now I'm using a free API called tweepy in Python to download tweets from twitter with a particular hashtag within a timeframe.

Mainly two problems I'm facing in tweepy:

1. It doesn't download an media files and just provides a link for it within that tweet
2. It doesn't download tweets that doesn't have text in them. (except the hashtag)

So, I was wondering if I use a licensed API (please recommend if any in mind) then will it download each and every tweet with that hashtag and within that timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweepy is a Python library that provides an interface to the Twitter API. Twitter has an API itself; Tweepy is a Python way of talking to the Twitter API.

The Twitter API only provides links to images and media. It is down to your own code to download the actual content. Tweepy doesn’t make any difference here. You will need to adapt your code to grab any media content from any URL in the Tweet object.

> It doesn't download tweets that doesn't have text in them. (except the hashtag)

I do not know what this means. Tweepy as a library does not download anything at all. It requests information from the Twitter API. You need to write code to download anything you want to keep.

Comment: okay, I understand your point. Actually I didn't know that info about tweepy and Twitter API. So thanks for that. As far my question goes, I didn't need the solution to the problems I'm facing in tweepy in this thread as I have open another thread for it. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68556060/14241197). You can take a look at it their. All i needed in this thread is information. So thanks for that. And now that I know that the Twitter API itself provides this info and I need to adapt the code, I will work on that and thanks for the tip.

Comment: Also, just to confirm, irrespective of the library I use (like tweepy or other libraries that do the same work), it will always return me the links of the media files right?

Comment: Yes, if you are interested in media, then there is the ability in the Twitter API v1.1 to get a link to the file. In v2 this is not currently the case but this is being worked on.

Comment: okay thanks for the info. But for now they do mention the links. I'm not sure whether the link is for the tweet or for the media file. On clicking the link it redirects to the tweet. So yeah. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: If this is API v1.1, make sure you include `tweet_mode=extended` as a parameter on your API call.